# How does the Mailbox app gestures work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gesture

I would like to know what the best way is to implement something like the new Mailbox App for iOS's gesture controls. For example, swiping to the right on an eMail allows you to mark that eMail as read.

How did they do it? (How do you think they did it?)

Here is the app:

[image]

Comment: Check out [alikaragoz](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell)' implementation on Github

Comment: @Paul.s make it an answer! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

from a conceptual point of view, it seems like it can be done by adding a swipeable subview on top of a regular cell. as you add a swipe gesture to the cell, you can "unveil" the cell underneath, showing the buttons.